# What is correct reverse of Double#longBitsToDouble()

Tags: java, double, long-integer

There are two potential reverse methods:

[`Double#doubleToRawLongBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits(double))

and

[`Double#doubleToLongBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double))

Which one to use to pack `double` into `long` correctly?

Comment: The answer is given in the links you provide. The only difference is the handling of NaN.